# Get output of shell command - odd difference between interactive PHP and PHP-CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have a long running PHP script that runs on a Raspberry Pi which periodically checks the CPU temperature via the following command:

```
exec('/bin/cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp')/1000
```

This works fine.

I also want to capture the CPU load by parsing the output of the top command run like so:

```
exec('/usr/bin/top -n 1 -p 0', $output, $code)
```

Oddly this only works if I run the PHP script interactively, it doesn't run when the script is executed under the PHP-CLI (started from the sudo crontab) yet the cat command runs under both.  The value of $code returned is 1 which seems to indicate that the process couldn't run or wouldn't run.

Why the difference and how would I get the output of top so that I can parse it ?

Comment: Does the call `var_dump($output);` gives you any useful information why the execution of `top` failed? If not, use `proc_open()` to execute the command and reading the `STDERR` stream from the application. You might also consider redirecting the `STDERR` stream to `STDOUT` and read it that way.

Comment: Nope, $output is just an empty array.  I've tried proc_open but the following code doesn't work so that doesn't really help: <?php

$cwd='/tmp';
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") );

$process = proc_open('""/usr/bin/top" "-n1" "-p0""', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd);

echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[1]);

?>